# How to solve the error "items.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Api = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const apiGet = () => {
    fetch("https://dummyjson.com/posts#")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setItems(json);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    apiGet();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <ul>
        {" "}
        {items.posts.map((item) => (
          <li>{item.title} </li>
        ))}{" "}
      </ul>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Api;
```

I tried to target the property which contain the array but still I'm getting this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: [how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What does `console.log(items.posts)` show?

Comment: Also your initial state is an array, which doesn't have a `posts` property. The `useEffect` will only run *after* the first render.

Answer (score 1):

The first time Api component is mounted your items initial state is an array so when u try to access posts property he will not find it.
Try to destructure the posts from the json and loop directly.
Try this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Api = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const apiGet = () => {
    fetch("https://dummyjson.com/posts#")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({posts}) => {
        setItems(posts);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    apiGet();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <ul>
        {" "}
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li>{item.title} </li>
        ))}{" "}
      </ul>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Api;
```